# Installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 and formating partitions

Tags: system-installation, format

I will install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7. Will any partition be formated,or things will stay as they are?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score 2):

**Backup everything** before doing any changes, as usual. (Helps a lot if something goes wrong)

You are using Windows 7, so I suppose you will not have troubles regarding secure boot, UEFI etc.

You have several options:

1. Doing the formatting prior to the installation
2. Using Ubuntu's auto-formatter
3. Doing a manual formatting while installing

Personally I use  **1** . But Windows cannot resize a partition in use beyond a certain point (usually C:), which is when you have to do the resizing while installing Ubuntu (2. or 3.). If you plan to have several different partitions in a special Layout I recommend 3., but for a beginner I would recommend 2.

### Resources:

1. http://www.wikihow.com/Partition-Your-Hard-Drive-in-Windows-7
2. [Safety of installing Ubuntu alongside Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80604/safety-of-installing-ubuntu-alongside-windows)
3. [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)