# Will Ubuntu format and erase the partition I intend to install it on?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, hard-drive, format

I've never installed Ubuntu (or any linux distro) on a hard drive before but now I want to install it on a partition and have a dual-boot setup with Windows 7 being on the C drive and Ubuntu on the other partition.

Will Ubuntu wipe the partition clean? Or can/will Ubuntu install without formatting it?

It's a 50GB partition, it doesn't have an OS installed on it but I have about 30GB's worth of data stored on it. Do I need to copy that data to a different drive temporarily then copy it back after Ubuntu is installed?

Thanks!

Comment: In theory, there is a checkbox to format the partition.  You can make sure it's unchecked.  However, I can't tell you exactly what to do, because there are issues with secure boot and UEFI with Windows that I have successfully avoided, so I don't have experience with those issues.

Comment: Thanks Marty. I'm not sure what you're referring to when you mention issues with secure boot and UEFI but I'm glad you told me about the checkbox to uncheck to keep it from formatting the drive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Safety of installing Ubuntu alongside Windows](http://askubuntu.com/questions/80604/safety-of-installing-ubuntu-alongside-windows)

Comment: David Foerster, I can't imagine why you said my post was a possible duplicate of one that was posted near three years ago by somebody else. But nevertheless, I read that thread and it was somewhat helpful so thanks for providing me the link to it.

Answer (score 0):

Given that setup, I would resize the existing partition with the data on it to be smaller, then install Ubuntu into a new partition in the new free space.

I think this would be less risk, and would allow Ubuntu to be installed on a more Linux friendly filesystem (EXT) than the existing Windows (NTFS/FAT) partition

Comment: Thanks matt. I never knew that Linux created its' own filesystem (EXT) so I imagine creating a new partition would be better then. Guess I'll have to move the data and put it back when it's done. Question is though, if Linux creates a new filesystem, will that partition be recognized and accessible when booted up in Windows?

Comment: The general rule is Linux will play nice with windows but not the other way around.  So you could install Linux on a windows NTFS/FAT file system, whilst i wouldnt recommend you I can point to any specific problems you may experience.  Conversely as you ask, Windows will not be able to see/read a Linux created (non fat32/ntfs) file system.

Comment: And yes, I would suggest moving the existing data out the way to some where separate to avoid accidental loss

Comment: Thanks again matt. I had a feeling Windows wouldn't recognize it. So, if I were to format the partition to EXT when installing Linux, when I were then booted up off the Linux OS, would the other drive's (NTFS/FAT) partitions still be recognized by Linux then? I imagine they would be since you said Linux plays nice with Windows but I don't know if it's different when Linux is on EXT versus NTFS/FAT. Yes, I'd find out after going through the process but it would be nice to know in advance. And also, does Linux run faster and more efficiently if the drive were formatted to EXT?

Answer (score 0):

I think that will be better to create another partition with those free 20GB. If I remember right, in installation process it ask you to format it (it isn't imperative I think).

Also, even not formatting it, it could overwrite your data so I suggest you to create another partition (20GB) or move the data elsewhere and install it in the 50GB partition formatting it.

Comment: Thanks Shlikstr. I'd rather not create another partition so I'll just relocate the 30GB's of data then move it back afterwards, just to be on the safe side.